# JSON representation of the following nested data

Tags: python, json, fsm

I am writing code to empirically determine the [state transition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_transition_table) from data generated by a natural process. I want to derive the states from the data, and then save the state data to HD, for later querying.

From the analysis I have done so far, the state information is nested, and the system has N (fixed at N=3 for simplicity) distinct states. Furthermore, each of these N states has a fixed (variable number) of nested states.

This is the (pseudo YAML) schema I have come up with so far:

```
machine-state:
    frequency_1: state-info
    frequency_2: state-info
    frequency_3: state-info

state-info: 
    classification_1:
        - classification_1_state_foo
        - classification_1_state_foobar
        - classification_1_state_foofoo
        - classification_1_state_foofoobar
        - classification_1_state_foobarfoo

    classification_2:
        - classification_2_state_name1
        - classification_2_state_name2
        - classification_2_state_name3
        - classification_2_state_name4

    classification_3:
        - classification_3_state_anothername
        - classification_3_state_anothername1
        - classification_3_state_anothername2
        - classification_3_state_anothername3
```

It seems the various classifications of the state machine (classification_*) can derive from an ABC. However, I'm not sure how to represent this tree structure in JSON, for simple querying etc.

I am using Python, and intend to store the JSON documents in PostgreSQL db as the backend - so I can query the JSON documents, so I can empirically build a state transition table from the stored data.

My question is, given the problem I'm trying to model (and the sample YAML above)- how may I best represent the data in a JSON model?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything better than the most intuitive representation:

```
{
    "classification1": [
        "classification_1_state_foo",
        "classification_1_state_foobar",
        "classification_1_state_foofoo",
        ...
    ],
    "classification2": [
    ...
}
```

However, as we are talking about tree structure, maybe JSON is not the best choice here. If I may suggest a radical change in your approach, you might consider building this data in XML instead, saving the XML data in a file and using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to query it. Example:

```
<classification>
    <classification_state>classification_1_state_foo</classification_state>
    <classification_state>classification_1_state_foobar</classification_state>
    <classification_state>classification_1_state_foofoo</classification_state>
    ...
</classification>
...
```